# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden php

Tags: php, google-api, google-books

"Sometime" I get Error

> file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=xxxxxx):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

my php

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    //isset($postdata) {
        //$request = ($postdata);

        $isbn = $_GET['isbn'];



       $path = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:".$isbn."";

        $jsondata = file_get_contents($path);
            $jsons = json_decode($jsondata,true);

            echo json_encode($jsons);


?>
```

Comment: Could it be because you have exceeded your access limit for the day or hour or something like that

Comment: Yes, this will happen when there are too many requests within a short time from the same IP address. You need to register an account with Google, get an API key (server key) for the API and send that key with every request.

Comment: How to fix this?

Comment: @ARR.s as I said, you need an apikey https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#APIKey

Comment: Then if you have the key for example abcde, add to the URL like this: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=xxxxxx&key=abcde

Comment: @NineBerry hey , I try this your answer. I got it thank you! :)